# FullCalendar.js - 7 days only (no actual dates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm setting a weekly scheduling system which is not linked to actual dates, but rather days in the week. So Monday-Sunday.

I've achieved this in FullCalendar using the following:

```
defaultView: 'basicWeek',
columnFormat: 'ddd',
```

However I now have issues displaying the events that are read from my DB, as I can only get FullCalendar to display dates that are in a standard full date format.

My options are:

1) Set an invisible date range (Eg, 2017-01-01 - 2017-01-07) and save all events within this range (invisible to the user but operational on backend)

2) Try and store the dates as Mon/Tue/Wed and load natively into FullCalendar

I'm aiming for the 2nd!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `getDay()` function to get the day of the week. (int)

> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date. 
>  **Note**: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on. - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

Example:

```js
var d = new Date('2017-04-26');
var n = d.getDay();  
alert(n); // will be 3 => Wednesday
```

Comment: The issue isn't in storing/converting dates, but in FullCalender rendering them. Initialising with a day in the format '3' for example gives the warning: `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions.`

Comment: It's not about converting to the correct format, it's about establishing whether FullCalendar has the ability to load just days and not full dates. I guess this requires somebody familiar with FullCalendar